# ESP-IDF platformio build: Contents of segment at SHA256 digest offset 0xb0 are not all zero

Tags: esp32, esp-idf, platformio

I am trying to run the [led-blink example](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/get-started/blink) from ESP-IDF with platformio. My target board is esp32-c6-devkitc-1.

Following the [platformio doc](https://docs.platformio.org/en/stable/frameworks/espidf.html#esp-idf-components) I added the led_strip component by downloading and copying the `espressif_led_strip_2.4.3` folder under `components` and added `idf_component.yml` in my `src` folder. However at the end of the compilation I got this error message:

```
A fatal error occurred: Contents of segment at SHA256 digest offset 0xb0 are not all zero. Refusing to overwrite.
*** [.pio\build\esp32-c6-devkitc-1\firmware.bin] Error 2
```

For which I don't have a clue. Any suggestions what I might have done wrong?

Comment: FYI you don't need to create the `components` folder and download the component manually. If you just put the `idf_component.yml` in the `src` directory, any esp components will be downloaded and put into a directory created and named `managed_components` automatically. Add `managed_components` to your `.gitignore`.

Comment: I am getting the same error using the same esp32-c6 board and led-blink-example. I tried a lot of different things but cannot get it to work with PlatformIO.

Comment: I actually started using the official IDF plugin for VS code and it works pretty well so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually ditched Platform.io and used the idf.py provided by the IDF package for compilation and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of an answer, but I am hoping it will provide more information.  I am building with ESP32-C6 and I get the same error message.

```
A fatal error occurred: Contents of segment at SHA256 digest offset 0xb0 are not all zero. Refusing to overwrite.
[.pio/build/esp32-c6-devkitm-1/firmware.bin] Error 2
```

I also get:

```
Warning! Flash memory size mismatch detected. Expected 4MB, found 2MB!
```

Building if I pull out some of my modules/code, I can get it to compile and flash.  It seems I've crossed over a boundary someplace.

I build using raw esp32-idf and got none of the above errors, and it deployed correctly and executed.